# Problem inserting into sqflite using Flutter

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter, dart, sqflite

I´m having problems with sqflite in Flutter.
Normal inserts work just fine... but as soon as I insert a value, which is the `id` I get from inserting int into the first table, I get a syntax error near ")".

This is the error I get:

> flutter: error DatabaseException(Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "near
> ")": syntax error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=near ")": syntax
> error}) sql 'CREATE TABLE pageM (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,caardId
> INTEGER,title INTEGER,content TEXT,)' args []} during open, closing...
> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
> DatabaseException(Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "near ")": syntax
> error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=near ")": syntax error}) sql
> 'CREATE TABLE pageM (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,caardId INTEGER,title
> INTEGER,content TEXT,)' args []}
> #0      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11:7) 
> #1      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:78:7)
> #2      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.safeInvokeMethod (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:208:15)
> #3      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.invokeExecute (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:370:12)
> #4      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnExecute. (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:362:14)
> #5      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:312:26)
> #6      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnWriteSynchronized (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:345:<…>

Here my insert:

```
onPressed: () async {
    currentCaard = Caard(topicId: widget.topicId, pageAmount: widget.pageAmount);
    print(currentCaard);
    currentCaard.id = await DatabaseProviderCaard.db.insert(currentCaard);
    currentPage = PageM(caardId: currentCaard.id, title: textControllerTitle.text,content: textControllerContent.text);
    DatabaseProviderPage.db.insert(currentPage);
},
```

and here is my whole db Provider file:

```
import 'package:caards/model.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

class DatabaseProviderCaard {
  static const String TABLE_CAARD = "caard";
  static const String COLUMN_ID = "id";
  static const String COLUMN_TOPIC_ID = "topicId";
  static const String COLUMN_PAGE_AMOUNT = "pageAmount";

  DatabaseProviderCaard._();
  static final DatabaseProviderCaard db = DatabaseProviderCaard._();

  Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    print("caard database getter called");

    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }

    _database = await createDatabase();

    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> createDatabase() async {
    String dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();

    return await openDatabase(
        join(dbPath, 'caardDB.db'),
        version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database  database, int version) async {
        print("Creating caard table");

        await database.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_CAARD ("
              "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
              "$COLUMN_TOPIC_ID INTEGER,"
              "$COLUMN_PAGE_AMOUNT INTEGER"
              ")",
          );
        },
    );
  }

  Future<List<Caard>> getCaards() async {
    final db = await database;

    var caards = await db
        .query(TABLE_CAARD, columns: [COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TOPIC_ID, COLUMN_PAGE_AMOUNT]);

    List<Caard> caardList = List<Caard>();

    caards.forEach((currentCaard) {
      Caard caard = Caard.fromMap(currentCaard);

      caardList.add(caard);
    });

    return caardList;
  }

  Future<int> insert(Caard caard) async {
    final db = await database;
    caard.id = await db.insert(TABLE_CAARD, caard.toMap());
    return caard.id;
  }

  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    final db = await database;

    return await db.delete(
      TABLE_CAARD,
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }

  Future<int> update(Caard caard) async {
    final db = await database;

    return await db.update(
      TABLE_CAARD,
      caard.toMap(),
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [caard.id],
    );
  }
}


class DatabaseProviderPage {
  static const String TABLE_PAGE = "page";
  static const String COLUMN_ID = "id";
  static const String COLUMN_CAARD_ID = "caardId";
  static const String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
  static const String COLUMN_CONTENT = "content";


  DatabaseProviderPage._();
  static final DatabaseProviderPage db = DatabaseProviderPage._();

  Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    print("page database getter called");

    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }

    _database = await createDatabase();

    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> createDatabase() async {
    String dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();

    return await openDatabase(
      join(dbPath, 'pageDB.db'),
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (Database  database, int version) async {
        print("Creating page table");

        await database.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_PAGE ("
              "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
              "$COLUMN_CAARD_ID INTEGER,"
              "$COLUMN_TITLE INTEGER,"
              "$COLUMN_CONTENT TEXT,"
              ")",
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<List<PageM>> getPages() async {
    final db = await database;

    var pages = await db
        .query(TABLE_PAGE, columns: [COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_CAARD_ID, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_CONTENT]);

    List<PageM> pageList = List<PageM>();

    pages.forEach((currentPage) {
      PageM page = PageM.fromMap(currentPage);

      pageList.add(page);
    });

    return pageList;
  }

  Future<PageM> insert(PageM pageM) async {
    final db = await database;
    pageM.id = await db.insert(TABLE_PAGE, pageM.toMap());
    return pageM;
  }

  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    final db = await database;

    return await db.delete(
      TABLE_PAGE,
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }

  Future<int> update(PageM page) async {
    final db = await database;

    return await db.update(
      TABLE_PAGE,
      page.toMap(),
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [page.id],
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my Model:

````
import 'package:caards/database_provider.dart';

class Caard {
  int id;
  int topicId;
  int pageAmount;

  Caard({this.id, this.topicId, this.pageAmount});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      DatabaseProviderCaard.COLUMN_ID: id,            //versuch
      DatabaseProviderCaard.COLUMN_TOPIC_ID: topicId,
      DatabaseProviderCaard.COLUMN_PAGE_AMOUNT: pageAmount
    };
    
    if (id != null) {
      map[DatabaseProviderCaard.COLUMN_ID] = id;
    }
    
    return map;
  }
  
  Caard.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map[DatabaseProviderCaard.COLUMN_ID];
    topicId = map[DatabaseProviderCaard.COLUMN_TOPIC_ID];
    pageAmount = map[DatabaseProviderCaard.COLUMN_PAGE_AMOUNT];
  }
}



class PageM {
  int id;
  int caardId;
  String title;
  String content;

  PageM({this.id, this.caardId, this.title, this.content});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      DatabaseProviderPage.COLUMN_CAARD_ID: caardId, 
      DatabaseProviderPage.COLUMN_TITLE: title,
      DatabaseProviderPage.COLUMN_CONTENT: content
    };

    if (id != null) {
      map[DatabaseProviderPage.COLUMN_ID] = id;
    }

    return map;
  }

  PageM.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map[DatabaseProviderPage.COLUMN_ID];
    caardId = map[DatabaseProviderPage.COLUMN_CAARD_ID];
    title = map[DatabaseProviderPage.COLUMN_TITLE];
    content = map[DatabaseProviderPage.COLUMN_CONTENT];
  }
}

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to syntactically correct the SQL query.
You currently use:

```
'CREATE TABLE pageM (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,caardId INTEGER,title INTEGER,content TEXT,)'
```

This query has an extra comma in the end, which is not syntactically correct. That is why the DB complains about a syntax error. In fact in the error message of the DB there is the query created using the code, inside which there is a trailing comma ',' before the parenthesis. Change your code so that the query is:

```
 'CREATE TABLE pageM (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,caardId INTEGER,title INTEGER,content TEXT)'
```

You need to change the following part in the DB Provider file.
The error is caused because there is a comma after `TEXT` in the following part:

```
 await database.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_PAGE ("
              "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
              "$COLUMN_CAARD_ID INTEGER,"
              "$COLUMN_TITLE INTEGER,"
              "$COLUMN_CONTENT TEXT,"
              ")",
```

A correct version would be the following.

```
await database.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_PAGE ("
              "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
              "$COLUMN_CAARD_ID INTEGER,"
              "$COLUMN_TITLE INTEGER,"
              "$COLUMN_CONTENT TEXT"
              ")",
```